# dygraphs change background colour

Tags: css, r, dygraphs

how to change the background colour when using the dygraphs in R.

I am looking in the CSS options (https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/gallery-css-styling.html) hoping to change the background but can't find anything.

The graph will eventually end up in a shiny dashboard, would I need to change the CSS there instead?

I am hoping to change the background to black.

A reproducible example would be the one provided in the link.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: if you want to change only the colour of the background of the plot, you could try to use: dygraph(nhtemp, main = "New Haven Temperatures") %>% dyShading(from = "1912-1-1", to = "1971-1-1", color = "black")

Comment: Nice trick! It will do for an answer, but feel like its a bit of a hack...rather than a fully fledged solution. Having said that happy to accept it as answer if you put it in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just copying my comment, you could use as an alternative:

```
dygraph(nhtemp, main = "New Haven Temperatures") %>% 
dyShading(from = "1912-1-1", to = "1971-1-1", color = "black")
```